# Is there a universal property for branched coverings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $\eta: \mathbb{A}^1 \to X$ is a morphism of varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, such that for each $b \in \mathbb{A}^1$, $\eta(b)$ only depends on $b^2$, i.e. $\eta(b) = \eta(-b)$. Does it follow that $\eta$ factors over the following branched covering?
\begin{align*}
f\colon\mathbb{A}^1 & \to \mathbb{A}^1 \\
b & \mapsto b^2
\end{align*}
That is, is there a map $\xi: \mathbb{A}^1 \to X$ such that $\eta = \xi \circ f$?

Set-theoretically (at least on closed points) it is clear. Even in the analytic contex, I could locally choose the branch of the logarithm, define a square root, and then patch the local functions together. But how can one formally show this in the context of algebraic geometry?

Comment: $b^2\in\mathbb{A}^2$ means what?

Comment: @Mohan Sorry, it should mean $b^2 \in \mathbb{A}^1$. It is now corrected.

Comment: Let $C$ be the image of $\eta$ and let $D$ its normalization. Then $\eta$ factors through $D$ and since your hypothesis implies that it factors through $\xi$ since $D$ is normal.